# How to have an optional argument type in a generic function type?

Tags: typescript, generics

I have a generic function type that looks like this:

```
type Test<TArg> = (arg: TArg) => void;
```

Most of the time, the argument is used by functions conforming to this type:

```
let x1: Test<number> = (n) => { console.log(n) };
let x2: Test<string> = (s) => { alert(s) };
```

Sometimes though, I have a function that doesn't take any arguments:

```
let y1: Test<undefined> = () => { };
```

I'd like to be able to invoke this function without providing any arguments at the callsite like this:

```
y1();
```

But no matter what types I plug in for `TArg`, I can't seem to do that. Is there anyway to do this without making the parameter optional in the definition of `Test`?

Here's what I've tried:

```
type Test<TArg> = (arg: TArg) => void;

let x: Test<number> = (n) => { console.log(n) };
let y1: Test<never> = () => { };
let y2: Test<any> = () => { };
let y3: Test<undefined> = () => { };
let y4: Test<null> = () => { };

x(1);
y1(); //Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.
y2(); //Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.
y3(); //Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.
y4(); //Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.
```

Comment: sometimes having an argument and sometimes not is the definition of an optional function parameter. Why not make it optional?

Comment: For `y3` I can imagine you want to call it without arguments, but why it is a good idea to call `y2` and `y4` without arguments? `null` and `any` are concrete types with instances and doesn't make sense not to send an argument. For `y3`, make it simply optional.

Comment: Basically, when `TArg = (string | number | object)` etc it is required. I'm looking for some type of `TArg` that doesn't require me to pass a value at the call site.

Comment: @Wickoo Yes, you're right. I'm simply providing the code I've already tried. `never` seemed like logicially it should work but it didn't.

Comment: FWIW I don't think this is possible at the moment. However, if [this pull request](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/21316) ever lands, you might be able to use that feature to get what you want here.

Comment: @CRice Thanks, if you post answer that says it currently isn't possible, I'll accept that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If having an execution wrapper is acceptable, I've come up with a solution that handles either function length (0 or 1), and is type safe for the argument:

```
type Test<T> = (arg?: T) => void;

class Wrapper<T, F extends Test<T>> {
    public execute: F;

    public static create<T1, F1 extends Test<T1>>(method: F1): Wrapper<T1, F1> {
        return new Wrapper(method);
    }

    constructor(method: F) {
        this.execute = method;
    }
}

const func1 = Wrapper.create((a: string) => console.log(a));
const func2 = Wrapper.create(() => { });

func1.execute('3');
func2.execute();

func1.execute(5); // 5 is not assignable to type "string"
func1.execute(); // expected 1 argument
func2.execute(5); // expected 0 arguments
```

Note if you wanted to expand this beyond 1 parameter you could add additional generic types but you'd have to manually define each one and carry it through the wrapper class, but it would work.

**EDIT** removed original optional parameter solution